# How can I show one window when i use sympy plot_implicit?

Tags: python, sympy

I have a question about `plot_implicit` windows.

when I type this:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting import *

r1, r2 = symbols('r1 r2')
f = Function('f')
f = 1/r1 - 1/r2

p0=plot_implicit(Eq(f,1),(r1,-1,1),(r2,-1,1))
p1=plot_implicit(Eq(f,2),(r1,-1,1),(r2,-1,1))
p0.extend(p1)
p0.show()
```

3 windows are opened. (`p0 graph`, `p1 graph`, `p0&p1 graph`)

I want to show graph only  with two functions.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `show=False` of `plot_implicit` and only last figure will appear:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting import *

r1, r2 = symbols('r1 r2')
f = Function('f')
f = 1/r1 - 1/r2

p0=plot_implicit(Eq(f,1),(r1,-1,1),(r2,-1,1), show=False)
p1=plot_implicit(Eq(f,2),(r1,-1,1),(r2,-1,1), show=False)
p0.extend(p1)
p0.show()
```